# How can I create an MCQ paper for free?

Tags: discussion

I have to create an MCQ test for my students. I know I can use MS Word for that. I want to know if there is a free specialised tool for this.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You likely want to ask this question on the main site, not the meta site (this site is for questions about the ebooks site itself). https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/